# Error using wget in c++

Tags: c++, wget

I downloaded wget from gnuwin32 and I am trying to run the command in a c++ program using the system() function. I am using visual studio 2012 on a windows OS as my compiler. wget runs on the command line but does not run when I put it in the system function. My error is " 'wget' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file"

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

int main()
{
string str = string("wget -O test.csv \"http://")+"somewebsitelink\"";

    const char *x = str.c_str();
    cout << str << endl;
    system(x);

system("pause");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Do you have `wget` in your environment variables?

Comment: I followed the steps on this site:

http://noahcoad.com/post/614/using-wget-on-windows

Comment: add `wget` to `PATH`. You can use PathEditor which has a nice GUI to edit `PATH` environmental variable.

Comment: Or simply type this into your command line `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\wget\ `

Comment: My error is when I try and run it in visual studio 2012 while trying to run a c++ program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio is probably overriding your normal path somehow if it really is in the path and not working.

Just put the full path in manually:

system("c:/path/wget ...");

Comment: Can you elaborate please? I don't know what that means. Should I point to the bin directory of wget? Also, I am on a windows machine

Comment: Yeah that is it. I put in the full path directory C:/GnuWin32/bin/wget and it worked

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`wget` needs have its directory in the list of directories in your `PATH` environment variable.

Since you are using Windows, you'll have to modify it your user configuration.  It has been years since I have used windows, so I no longer recall exactly where it is.

Comment: If I go to start menu and go to cmd and use the wget command it works fine, but when I run the command inside a system() function in c++ it does not work.

Comment: Use getenv to see the environment that the OS is giving your applciation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/getenv It might have no relation to the environment of other programs.